# I hope someone can figure out why this function passes the wrong ID number tothe url

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamically populated table with 12 cells per row. The desired behavior is that when any of the 1st 11 cells in a row are clicked, a page opens with more details about the item in the row that was clicked. The problem I'm having is that, the number saved in variable id, on line 4, is always the id number of the last row of the table.(By the time the handler is writen to the cell) I've checked the contents of the variable and it's exactly what I'd expect until just after this line: **rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function(){

return function()
{**  The purpose of the j loop is to loop through first 11 cells of the row. The 12th cell contains a link to another routene.

```
function addRowHandlers(){//adds onclick handeler to the first 11 cells of each row. cell 0 contains id number.
var rows = document.getElementById("WDTable").rows;
for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) { 
    id = rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML; 
    for (j = 0; j < 11; j++) { 
        rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function(){  
        return function()
        {                        
//var id = rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML; tried to put this inside the j loop hoping it might fix my problem.
//if I uncomment line above get an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
        window.open("https://fwdb.link/weapons/"+id+";", "Details",height=757, width=900");
        };}(rows[i]);
        }
    }
}
window.onload = addRowHandlers();
```

Comment: I am not sure 100% but it is probably because of the execution context, try wrapping it in an IIFE, and if it doesn't mean anything for you that I would recommend checking out how js works under the hood when the code gets executed. recommend 'javascript the weird parts on udemy'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your `onclick` handlers close over the same `id` variable. The value of that variable at the time these handlers execute will be whatever value was assigned to it last - in your case the last row.

You should declare `id` with `let` in order to bind it to the outermost `for loop` block, so that each iteration of the loop - and thus each set of handlers for a given row - has its own copy of the `id` variable.